# Magento randomly shows blank page

Tags: magento, caching, magento-1.7

Every once in a while my Magento website shows a blank page. No errors, not anything: just a white page. When this occurs, the fix is to clear my caches. After that the website works again for a month or so and after that the same problem occurs.

Any ideas on how to cure this?

Comment: have tou enabled cache from admin?

Comment: Are you using Varnish, Redis or any third party caching extension on your site? Full page cache extension?

Comment: I am using Byte for caching

Comment: Can you ask your hosting provider for get sql log or server is in memory overflow ?

Comment: Your bug appear exactly every month (at fixed date/time) ?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time this problem occur by cache memory full. At the beginning, I manually remove the files in home/var/cache/ after that the site is working perfectly. But this is not a good approach.

This is the way Now I found. (make a Cron job to clear automatically)
add a bash script in root folder Magento with this code.

```
#in root sh
rm -rf /root/yoursitepath/var/cache/*
rm -rf /root/yoursitepath/var/session/*
rm -rf /root/yoursitepath/var/report/*
```

replace /root/your site path with your site var/cache folder path.

And add a Cron job in Cpanel. like every 12hours like:

```
 *  */12    *   *   * /bin/sh /chroot/home/your site path/html/magento_cache_syrup.sh
```

Thanks. Happy code. 
I already mention this on my blog, I update this with new method too. please visit for more about it
[Magento blank page Error](https://www.mazzitorch.com/2017/06/10/magento-blank-page-error-fix/)